# Не могу установить Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

При выполнении команды npm выдаёт эту ошибку

```
"create-nuxt-app" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\stasy\WebstormProjects\shop
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-nuxt-app app

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\stasy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-03T11_11_07_558Z-debug-0.log
```

Если использовать npx, то оно в целом не находит такой пакет, пишет что-либо неправильно название, либо такого пакета не существует.
Обыскался по всех форумах, но так и не нашёл решения, как это можно решить?

Вот логи установки

```
1 info using npm@8.19.2
2 info using node@v18.12.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\stasy\WebstormProjects\shop\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 4ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\stasy\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\stasy\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 14ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 14ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
22 verbose title npm init nuxt-app app
23 verbose argv "init" "nuxt-app" "app"
24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 4ms
27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\stasy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
28 verbose logfile C:\Users\stasy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-03T11_11_07_558Z-debug-0.log
29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
32 timing npm:load Completed in 28ms
33 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
34 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
35 silly logfile done cleaning log files
36 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-nuxt-app 226ms (cache revalidated)
37 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
38 timing command:init Completed in 484ms
39 verbose stack Error: command failed
39 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:63:27)
39 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
39 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
39 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
40 verbose cwd C:\Users\stasy\WebstormProjects\shop
41 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
42 verbose node v18.12.0
43 verbose npm  v8.19.2
44 error code 1
45 error path C:\Users\stasy\WebstormProjects\shop
46 error command failed
47 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-nuxt-app app
48 verbose exit 1
49 timing npm Completed in 627ms
50 verbose code 1
51 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
51 error     C:\Users\stasy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-03T11_11_07_558Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Добавьте команду, которой вы хотели установить Nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

Искал ответ я долго, в принципе правильный был понизить версию ноды до 14, но я поступил иначе и установил всё через Laragon в котором у меня стоит 14 версия